# How can I specify a custom testcase name in the XML generated by PyTest

Tags: xml, junit, pytest

I am using Python to run a test case and generate an XML output. I would like to specify a custom name for the testcase element in the XML output, rather than using the default name which is the function name of the test case. How can I do this in Python, and what is the proper way to achieve it

Example:

```
def test_case_blalbla():
    assert True
```

generates the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<testsuites>
<testsuite name="pytest" errors="0" failures="0" skipped="0" tests="1" time="0.041"
           timestamp="2022-12-29T17:20:24.662571" hostname="my_hostname">
    <testcase classname="my_classname" name="test_case_balbla"
              time="0.021"/>
</testsuite>
```

I want

```
<testcase classname="my_classname" name="test_case_blabla"
              time="0.021"/>
```

to be

```
<testcase classname="my_classname" name="My test case blalbla"
              time="0.021"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying the name of the node id at the test collection stage using the following code:

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        path = item.nodeid.split("::")[0]
        initial_name = item.nodeid.split("::")[1].replace("test_", "")
        name = initial_name.capitalize().replace("_", " ") # You can name this however you like
        item._nodeid = f"{path}::{name}"
```

*Be careful though, because this may introduce unexpected side-effects. In my case, it works fine.*

**EDIT - Better alternative**

From [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/output.html#record-xml-attribute):
There is a built-in fixture called `record_xml_attribute` which can be used to change/overwrite the *attributes* of the XML tag .
This way you can change the "name" attribute and achieve your goal.
For example:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def change_testcase_name(record_xml_attribute):
    record_xml_attribute("name", "My new test case name")
```

In case you want to use this fixture inside a hook you can call it like this (the hook needs access to `request` object or anything relevant):

```
record_xml_attribute = request.getfixturevalue("record_xml_attribute")
record_xml_attribute("name", "My new test case name")
```

Comment: When I do the one with the decorator `@pytest.fixture()`, my JUnit XML does not contain a test case.

Comment: Without `pytest.fixture()`, it worked for me. So just `record_xml_attribute(...)`